# Algorithm to verify that a weak Nash equilibrium is an ESS, or a strict Nash equilibrium

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

Is there any algorithm that might assist me in checking whether a weak Nash equilibrium in a signalling game is also an Evolutionarily Stable Strategy, or a strict Nash?

Comment: Checking whether some profile is a strict Nash equilibrium or an ESS requires only a handful of checks. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Probably I'm just too ignorant. If one has a mixed strategy that is a weak Nash, it doesn't seem trivial to me, in general, to establish that every unilateral move away from the strategy will diminish payoffs. If this is a textbook problem and I am missing something obvious (entirely possible) please point me in the right direction.

Comment: A strict Nash equilibrium will always be pure. To verify that it is an ESS, you only have to test it against other pure strategies. This follows from the simple fact that there are always pure best replies. The mixed best replies are exactly the convex combinations of pure best replies.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker I should perhaps also point out that theorem 29.9 in (Nisan, ed.) Algorithmic Game Theory states that "Given a 2-player, symmetric game F and a strategy s, it is coNP-hard to compute whether or not s is an ESS of F".

Comment: Of course. Thanks. That point does not carry over to ESS, does it?

Comment: Well, the number of pure best responses to check grows nonlinearly in the number of strategies in a symmetric game. Depending on your applications, this might be a problem. But for reasonable games you can actually write down on a piece of paper, this should not be an issue.